# Adsense: Your site isn’t ready to show ads

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

My site was showing ads all fine, but then I decided to rebrand and change the domain name of my site.
So my new domain is uncutacademy.com

I did make changes to the webmaster's console (search console) and have added the site as my property, also I have moved the site as well. see image below

[image]

I have now added the domain to my AdSense and applied for monetization of the new domain and removed ads from my previous domain.

I was till now getting the COVID error as the staff was low at Google HQ. Now I am getting policy violation as shown below

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nBeX0WK.png]

This feels so bizarre as I had an active account and was generating revenue and now it says I have a policy violation.

Kindly let me know what is to be done here.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think your website is not have enough content or You have not getting enough traffic on your website... Try to Increase your website traffic.. That's It...

Comment: There are no minimum traffic requirements to be approved for AdSense.  There are minimum content requirements, but presumably they have enough if the website had already been approved on the old domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Enough traffic is need before AdSense Approval.... without traffic this is very hard to get approved... This is happened with me also but when my site getting daily only 70+ Organic (From Search Engine) Traffic then I got the approval.

Comment: I do not think traffic is an issue here. It is not mentioned in any terms page. Also, I am getting over 500+ daily unique visits so that is not the case.